# Data not loading in table from observable angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, observable

I am loading a table by getting data from service. I am subscribing to data but I am not able to load it in a table. My code snippet is below :

TS:

```
this.demoService.uploadCSV(a,b).subscribe((Response: any) => {
    console.log("Response is ",Response); //giving undefined
    this.csvColumns = Response.response.fields
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="csvTable" class="table table-view">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of csvColumns;">
            <tr>
             <td>{{data.columnName}}</td>
             </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Service.ts

```
  uploadCSV(a,b): Observable<any> { 
    return this.httpClient.post(URL, {"a":a,"b":b});
  }
```

Comment: post code of uploadCSV(a,b,) function in demoService

Comment: If `Response` is undefined I'd guess this is an error with the backend where you get your data from. Can you verify that the backend yields the correct response (e.g. with Postman)?

Comment: I can see the response in network tabs in dev tools

Comment: @user9040429, Whether there is comma after ```b``` in your real application or by mistake you have made it here? ```uploadCSV(a,b,)```. If so please remove it..

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors in the console? Issue is probably that you try to use `*ngFor` with an undefined value.

Two different solutions for your issue:

Use the observable directly

```
// In TS
csvColumns$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.csvColumns$ = this.demoService.uploadCSV(a,b).pipe(map(d => d.response.fields);
}

// in HTML
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of csvColumns$ | async;">
  <tr>
    <td>{{data.columnName}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Or define the list as an empty array until you have data

```
// In TS
csvColumns: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.demoService.uploadCSV(a,b).subscribe(response => {
    if(response)
      this.csvColumns = response.response.fields;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.demoService.uploadCSV(a,b).subscribe(Response => {
  if(Response) {
    console.log("Response is ", Response);
    this.csvColumns = Response.response.fields
  }
}
```